# Using bookdown, must one set number_sections: true in _output.yml for cross referencing sections?

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

I'm able to render an HTML book using Bookdown, but cross referencing sections is failing.

I can make it work, however.  First, I'll make the cross referencing work.

**Edit 9/20/20 12:15 pst in response to a request for a more repex**

My chapter heading looks like this:

```
# Getting Articles {#getArt}
```

The cross reference in a different chapter looks like this, a text excerpt:

> you'll need to walk through the steps found in the Getting Articles section \@ref(getArt) )

This reference works when _output.yml's `number_sections: true`, but not when `number_sections: false`

**end edit**

In my _output.yml I have the following code; the comment on the last line is my issue:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
 css: style.css
 toc_depth: 4
 number_sections: true    # if true, cross reference section labels render correctly
```

If I set `number_sections true` then I may correctly cross reference to sections, like this where it reads "...in the Getting Articles section 2" :

> Jay Efran (2007) (to obtain this article, you’ll need to walk through the steps found in the Getting Articles section 2 )

But if my _output.yml looks like this:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
 css: style.css
 toc_depth: 4
 number_sections: false
```

I get the following (note the "??"):

> Jay Efran (2007) (to obtain this article, you’ll need to walk through the steps found in the Getting Articles section **??** )

According to [Yuhui's bookdown text, section 2.6](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html), it states the following about cross referencing and the "??":

> When a referenced label cannot be found, you will see two question marks like ??, as well as a warning message in the R console when rendering the book.

But I am at a loss as what to do.  Clearly, the cross reference is there and correctly works but only under the _output.yml condition `number_sections:` is set to `true`.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Hard to diagnose without a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How do you reference Section 2?

Comment: Well, the reproducible example is hard to make more than what I've already given; the actual way that I reference is just as instructed by that same link to chapter 2.6. it's like this:.     '\@ref(label)'. Note that it works in one condition, but not the other.

Comment: I've made an edit to show how a section/chapter is cross referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is that bookdown converts `\@ref(getArt)` (where `getArt` is the ID of your section) to a link to that section and sets the section number as the link text. For HTML output this looks roughly like this:

`<a href="chapter_title.html#getArt">2</a>`

(see the [source](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/R/gitbook.R) on GitHub)

If you set `number_sections: false` there is no chapter number, hence the link text is "??". In this respect, the documentation is somewhat inaccurate (because the reference exists and the link actually works).

The workaround is to manually assign an ID to the section header and reference it like this:

```
You'll need to walk through the steps found in the 
[Getting Articles section](#getArt).
    
# Getting Articles {#getArt}
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you. This part is what demonstrated my ignorance:

`<a href="chapter_title.html#getArt">2</a>`

Comment: And it works whether or not `number_sections:` is set to true.

What is lost, however, is the fancy formatting of a number.  I suppose that makes sense because if number_sections: is set to false, numbers become meaningless.